# Can cyclopropane be synthesized from propan-1-ol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I know the dehydration of propan-1-ol derives in prop-2-ene by removal of the hydroxyl group and a hydrogen atom from the second carbon, but could the hydrogen come from the ones bonded to the third one?

Comment: And why would it?

Answer (score 2):

At first look at how cyclopropane can be produced from a haloalkane

[image]

This is the creation of cyclopropane by Zn metal reduction of terminal vicinal dihalide. Actually cyclopropane is a highly strained molecule and it's production is quite unfavorable, it is anyways produced in this reaction due to the presence of Cl at both ends.

When Zn is introduced to 1,3-dichloropropane, it abstracts the two Cl atoms and produce two $\ce {Cl^-}$ ions. This means there is a lack of electrons in the propane chain as each Cl atom takes away an extra electron. Due to this there can't be unsaturation in propane to make propene and thus the reaction proceeds toward cyclization to make cyclopropane.

But cyclopropane **cannot** be made from   propane-1-ol. See this reaction:

[image]

This reaction occurs in the presence of a protic acid e.g. $\ce {H2SO4}$ or $\ce {H3PO4}$. The $\ce{H^+}$ from these protic acids attacks oxygen of propane-1-ol to leave behind a carbocation and elimination of $\ce{ H2O}$. The carbocation, which is quite unstable  and it will get to be stabilize by picking up electrons from the nearby $\ce {C-H}$ bond. This creates a double bond between the two C atoms and elimination of $\ce H^+$. So the formation of carbocation is what makes the conversion of propane-1-ol to propene and rules out the formation of cyclopropane.